# 301 Redirect Module compatability with Sitecore 9

Tags: redirect

the 301 Redirect Module doesn't say that it supports Sitecore 9

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/3/301_Redirect_module.aspx?sc_lang=en

Has anyone tried setting it up in Sitecore 9 and were there any issues?

Answer (score 1):

I have updated this module. You can download it from here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kqbkuwx07llbxsm/301%20Redirect%20Module9.0.1.zip?dl=0

Please test it very well, it was not tested too much but I had to do just one small change for upgrading from 8 to 9.

Comment: Hello Vlad, I tried this module and worked perfectly fine for Sitecore 9.2. However, I am not able to get it work for regular expression. I need to redirect any request that conatains "globalnews" in the url  to news page. I tried this as requested url ^http://mysite.local/globalnews/(.+)/$   and the source item is /sitecore/content/home

Comment: Now when i hit http://mysite.local/globalnews/news it throws 404 error

Comment: Hello! did you fixed that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're matching from the start of the URL, then you'll need to include "https://". Also, your pattern as written will only match URLs ending with a trailing slash. Experiment on https://regex101.com/ with "Flavor" set to "Python".

Comment: Is this answer related to using the 301 Redirect Module?

Comment: Yes, it was in response to what Kapil had said about it not working with regular expressions. His expression was not quite right, so it may work if corrected. 

I'll be trying the module in Sitecore 9.3 shortly.

Comment: Thanks! Just got confused about your comment about setting the flavor to Python :)